# A regex expression that select a specific character in a given word

Tags: regex

Example a regular expression that sélect the character « P » in all occurence of word « PARIS » in a text.

Having a text like :" I live in PARIS, my friend lives in PRAGUE. My father is coming to visit me in PARIS"
I just want to select « P » in the word « PARIS » and nowhere else

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: dude, that regex would literally be `P`. I sense you are asking for more than you are saying, so please expand your question to highlight the details of your query.

Comment: Do you want to match `P` in `PARIS`, but not `P` in (e.g.) `PRAGUE`. Please confirm. Do you want to match `P` in `COMPARISON`? (there's `PARIS` in it). What program or regex flavor (there are many) do you want solutions for? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes : 
Having a text like :" I live in PARIS, my friend lives in PRAGUE. My father is coming to visit me in PARIS"
I just want to select « P » in the word « PARIS » and nowhere else

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regex flavour, this should work:

```
\bP(?=ARIS\b)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/x84GKK/2)

Comment: Thank you very much. but if the character I would like to select is at the middle of the word. For example for the same sentence: 
" I live in PARIS, my friend lives in PRAGUE. My father is coming to visit me in PARIS" I just want to select « R » in the word « PARIS » and nowhere else

Comment: @spayt: In this case, use: `(?<=\bPA)R(?=IS\b)`

Comment: Thank you it works!

Comment: @spayt: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)